# How can I close the GUI window and print out some text using the inner class in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I want to print out some text as the window closes, but I want to do that by using the inner class.

I tried calling the windowClosing() method in main and some other things I can't recall right now, but generally none of it worked.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Sherlock extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   JTextField find = null;
   JTextArea mainText = null;

   public Sherlock()
   {  
      // JFrame code
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Sherlock search = new Sherlock();
      CloseTheWindow closeWin = search.new CloseTheWindow();
   }

   // Inner class prints out text when closing the window
   class CloseTheWindow extends WindowAdapter
   {  
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
      {
         System.out.println("Thank you for using finder");
           System.exit(0);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `addWindowListener()` on the `JFrame` and provide an instance of `CloseTheWindow` class which you have already written.

Try this code. It will give you the desired behavior.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Sherlock extends JFrame
{
  public Sherlock()
  {
    addWindowListener(new CloseTheWindow());
    // JFrame code
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Sherlock search = new Sherlock();
    search.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Sample Content"));
    search.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    search.setVisible(true);
  }

  // Inner class prints out text when closing the window
  class CloseTheWindow extends WindowAdapter
  {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
      System.out.println("Thank you for using finder");
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```